# debugging wp_cron jobs with XDebug in Eclipse

Tags: wp-cron, debug

I use Eclipse for PHP Developers (Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) in case it matters) and XDebug when developing plugins/themes.  It all works fine (i.e., I can set breakpoints in my plugin's code and step through it, etc).

However, I can't seem to get XDebug to stop at breakpoints in a function triggered by a 1-time [WP_Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) job.  For example, given the following:

```
add_action ('wpse_my_hook', 'wpse_my_cron_function') ;

function
wpse_my_function ()
{
    // schedule an immediate 1-time cron job
    wp_schedule_single_event (time (), 'wpse_my_hook', array ($some_data)) ;
}

function
wpse_my_cron_function ($some_data)
{
    $example = '' ; // set a breakpoint here

    // do something really cool :-)
}
```

and a breakpoint set at the 1st line in `wpse_my_cron_function()`, XDebug never stops there.  I know the function is being called (because of mods that function makes to the DB).

Is there something I need to do in my XDebug setup in order to debug [WP_Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) jobs or is it just not possible because of the way [WP_Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the answer to my question over on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146616/7751811)...and thought I'd copy the answer over here for future reference since WP folks are probably more likely to look here.

When [WP_Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/) fires a scheduled job it does so via a call to [wp_remote_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/).  The trick in that answer is to hook into [cron_request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/cron_request/) and add the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=idekey` query arg, as in

```
add_action ('cron_request', 'wpse_cron_add_xdebug_session_start', 10, 2) ;

function
wpse_cron_add_xdebug_session_start ($args, $doing_cron)
{
    $args['url'] = add_query_arg (array ('XDEBUG_SESSION_START' => 'ECLIPSE_DBGP'), $args['url']) ;

    return ($args) ;
}
```

That worked like a charm and I got my cron function debugged.

With my immediate need out of the way, I wanted a more general solution...one in which I didn't have to hard-code a specific IDE Key and this is what I came up with:

```
add_action ('cron_request', 'wpse_cron_add_xdebug_cookie', 10, 2) ;

/**
 * Allow debugging of wp_cron jobs
 *
 * @param array $cron_request_array
 * @param string $doing_wp_cron
 *
 * @return array $cron_request_array with the current XDEBUG_SESSION cookie added if set
 */
function
wpse_cron_add_xdebug_cookie ($cron_request_array, $doing_wp_cron)
{
    if (empty ($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) {
        return ($cron_request_array) ;
        }

    if (empty ($cron_request_array['args']['cookies'])) {
        $cron_request_array['args']['cookies'] = array () ;
        }
    $cron_request_array['args']['cookies']['XDEBUG_SESSION'] = $_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'] ;

    return ($cron_request_array) ;
}
```

I hope this helps others who have the same problem.